# how to set a trigger to add to a date in meteor using quickform

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have  *MemberProfiles* and *MemberPayments* collections.The *MemberProfile*  has *expiryDate* field which is set to current date at insert.I need to extend expirDate of a unique MemberProfile whenever a MemberPayment is added to that MemberProfile.

```
 MemberProfiles = new Mongo.Collection('memberProfiles');
 MemberProfileSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 expiryDate: {
   type: Date,

   autoValue: function () {

    return  moment().toDate();
    },

    autoform: {
        type: "hidden"
    }
} 

// to insert into Memb erProfiles
 {{> quickForm collection="MemberProfiles" id="insertMemberProfileForm"      type="insert" class="new-recipe-form"}}

 //the code for MemberPayments collection

 MemberPayments = new Mongo.Collection('memberPayments');

MemberPayments.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {

let memberProfile= MemberProfiles.direct.findOne({profile: doc.memberId});

  MemberProfiles.update(doc.memberId, {

    $set: {
         expiryDate: moment().add(31, 'days');
,
     }
 }
)
```

});

I have added all the necessary packages but still this doesnt work.I am getting error *Cannot set property 'expiryDate' of undefined*

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code where you perform the initial insert into MemberProfiles?

Comment: OK..., I am using a quickForm to insert into MemberProfiles.

Comment: Are you using the collection2 package too?

Comment: yes I am using collection2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is challenging to try and resolve issues like this without having a more complete example of the app or reference to the complete project in github or somewhere else.

However, when I read through your code I noticed an issue in your `MemberProfiles.update()` function.  I also noticed that it appears you are only processing your form from the client side (e.g. because your quickform is not using a Meteor Method) so you will have to manually call the SimpleSchema `.clean()` method to generate your autovalue.  Keep in mind that your client side approach might work ok now, but once you remove the `insecure` package you will either have to implement a Meteor Method to perform the insert or configure your collection allow/deny rules to allow client side insert (this is dangerous).

Since you are using `moment.js` you need to be careful that you always pull the date from the moment object before storing in mongodb.  In this case, you are trying to set `expiryDate` to the value returned from `moment().add(31, 'days')` which is just another moment object.

Also, I would assume you want to add 31 days to the current value of expiryDate, however you are never initializing moment with the expiryDate.  Therefore, you will always be setting the expiryDate to 31 days from the time the function executes.

Lastly, you have a syntax error (`;` inside your `$set` object) and your `findOne` selector includes `{profile: doc.memberId}` however your MemberProfiles schema says there is only a `_id` and `expiryDate` field in your collection.

Try this new logic that addresses the above issues and see if that resolves your issue.

```
MemberPayments.before.insert(function (userId, doc) {
  let memberProfile = MemberProfiles.direct.findOne({profile: doc.memberId});

  if (memberProfile) {
    if (!memberProfile.expiryDate) {
      console.log("expiryDate was not previously set!");
    } else {
      MemberProfiles.update({profile: doc.memberId}, {
        $set: {
          expiryDate: moment(memberProfile.expiryDate).add(31, 'days').toDate()
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    console.log("memberProfile not found");
  }
});
```

Now that this is fixed, you need to resolve the issue of your autovalue not being generated on the client side.  You do this by calling the SimpleSchema `.clean()` method.  Since you are not using Meteor Methods to process your quickForm (and therefore doing everything client side), you need to add the below AutoForm hook to ensure that the SimpleSchema `.clean()` method is called before the doc is saved (which will then execute your `autovalue` logic).

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  insertMemberProfileForm: {
    before: {
      insert: function(doc) {
        MemberProfileSchema.simpleSchema().clean(doc);
        return doc;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

You should put the above code in the `onRendered()` callback of the template that creates your quickform (e.g. the template that contains the below code in the HTML).

```
{{> quickForm collection="MemberProfiles" id="insertMemberProfileForm" type="insert" class="new-recipe-form"}}
```

Comment: I have attached my collection to the schema in both the collections.my autoValue function is fired.But when a MemberPayment is added the expiryDate of the particular MemberProfile is not updated.

Comment: @DilekaMadushan Ok, thats an important detail that you excluded from your question. Is anything else left out? The MemberProfile `update` code in your example looks incorrect. It says `days MemberProfiles.update(doc.memberId, date, {`. What is `days` and `date`. A copy paste error?

Comment: I want to add a month to the expiryDate of that particular memberProfile.That's what i have tried there.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DilekaMadushan I mean the line of code right after that in your example where you call MemberProfiles.update. Update take 2 params but you are passing 3. Also that line starts with `days` which is a syntax error. Is this copy paste error?

Comment: @DilekaMadushan did you fix the 3 arguments issue in the update function too? Look at my previous comment.

Comment: I corrected my update method but still it doesn't work

Comment: I corrected my update method to get only two parametres.Still the expiryDate of the memberProfile is not updated.

Comment: @DilekaMadushan see if this fixes it now.

Comment: It's exactly what i want to do and I tried your code and it still gives me " aldeed_autoform.js?hash=62240ad…:7780 TypeError: Cannot read property 'expiryDate' of undefined" error

Comment: @DilekaMadushan I updated the code in my answer again. If this doesn't solve it then the problem is not in the code you supplied. You will have to provide a more complete example (with more code) for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I tried the new code.Now the console shows "memerProfile not found".I just cant figure out why.Eventhough there is a memberProfile object in the specific collection i get the same message.

Comment: @DilekaMadushan add a console.log message and see what member id its not finding. Then look it up in your collection. You think its there, but is it actually?

Comment: Can we use the direct.findOne() method with parametres instead of the collection _id?.In my scenario MemberProfiles are accessed using the profile attribute in memberProfile schema.

Comment: @DilekaMadushan yes you can, i just made that change in my answer.

Comment: I corrected my code and now I don't get any error.But the expiryDate doesn't get changed.Instead the current time is set to expiryDate. :(

Comment: Clearly your expiryDate is not being set in the initial insert which means your autovalue is not being executed.  Since you are doing all of this client side you need to add an AutoForm hook to call SimpleSchema `.clean()`.  Check out my updated answer

Comment: Could you explain it further? When I insert a memberProfile the expiry date is set to the current date.Doesn't that mean the autoValue function is fired?

Comment: @DilekaMadushan ok, thats weird then. I changed the insert function one more time. Try the new one out.

Comment: Is it Autoform: hooks??? The AutoForm.hooks gives a syntax error when I put the code in the method Template. NewProfiles.onRendered

Comment: I tried your code and then it gave me an error"unauthorized code may only update by id".Therefore I tried with memberProfile._id as the ID in the update method.Then it worked.No errors were shown.Again the expiryDate was assigned the current date.It was not updated to 30 days.Is it an error with moment()?

Comment: @DilekaMadushan Who knows. If you send me a github link to your project I'll take a look at it, otherwise there is nothing else i can suggest.

Comment: I think I found the error.I created a defaultValue for expiryDate instead of a autoValue and created a Meteor.method() in the memberProfile.js and copied the above code in the method without keeping it in the memberPayment.js.Then I called the Meteor method in memberPayment.js.Then it worked :). Thank you very much for your kind advice.